# Detecting production vs. development React at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to detect whether the current version of React is development or production at runtime? I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (React.isDevelopment) {
  // Development thing
} else {
  // Real thing
}
```

Answer (score 327, accepted):

This is best done emulating the Node way of doing things with your build tool - webpack, browserify - by exposing `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Typically, you'll have it set to "production" in prod and "development" (or undefined) in dev.

So your code becomes:

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // dev code
} else {
    // production code
}
```

For how to set it up, see [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) or [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

Comment: This worked for me, once I had installed `browserify` and `envify`.

Comment: `process is not defined` on the client.

Comment: You need to use a build tool like webpack.

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be "development" in development mode.

Comment: Adding to @Joseph238's comment - when using create-react-app, `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be defined for you and you have access to it anywhere in your app. [See React documentation for detail](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

Comment: how do you import this process.env ?

Comment: @Joseph238 @ShaungCheng I've just created a fresh app using newest scripts using `create-react-app` but `process.env` doesn't have a variable `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: @ShaungCheng `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set in <https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L13>. Are you launching the app using "yarn start" and logging `process.env` inside the ES6 script? Webpack is probably inlining the process.env.NODE_ENV variable

Comment: For those using vite, import.meta.env.DEV as a boolean: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-variables

Answer (score 32):

I use a helper file (in Typescript):

```
import process from "process";

const development: boolean = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

export default function isDev(): boolean
{
    return development;
}
```

Then elsewhere I use it like this:

```
import isDev from "./helpers/DevDetect";

if (isDev())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: More lazier way: `export const isDev = () =>
  !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';`

Answer (score 7):

## `import.meta.env` should be all you need!

The `import.meta` object exposes context-specific metadata to a JavaScript module [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta)

As I see it, this is aligned with the newer esmodules import/export syntax, and is therefore the latest standard for reading environment variables in JS (and Typescript).

However, if `import.meta` is not available, then the env variables should be available to you in `process.env` (the good old commonJS way)

```
console.log(import.meta.env) // ...or process.env

/* dev */
{
  "MODE": "development",
  "DEV": true,
  "PROD": false,

}
/* prod */
{
  "MODE": "production",
  "DEV": false,
  "PROD": true,
}
```

this means you should be able to do stuff like

```
 import.meta.env.MODE;
 // or process.env.MODE;
```

OBS: the values inside the env object are different depending on what build tool your're using to run your app.

```
// create-react-app
{
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "PUBLIC_URL": "",
  "FAST_REFRESH": true
}

// vite-app
{
  "BASE_URL": "/",
  "MODE": "development",
  "DEV": true,
  "PROD": false,
  "SSR": false
}

// I haven't tested but I'm sure nextJS has it's own env setup
```

Comment: Seems like that's not standard, just something vite implemented. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15833

Answer (score 5):

I wanted access to this from the index.html and desired a solution which didn't involve ejecting webpack or configuring it with additional modules and I came up with this.

Sources are [David's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470995/2423207) and the [create-react-app documentation for using environment variables in the html file](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html)

```
if ( ! '%NODE_ENV%' || '%NODE_ENV%' === 'development') {
  // dev code
} else {
  // production code    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple environments in production as well. like testing (test branch), staging(staging branch) and production(master branch). Which you are handling with **CICD**

In this case, **process.env.NODE_ENV will return 'production' in all 3 environments**.

Hence If this is your case, I would recommend adding a variable in your **.env** files.

**.env.production**

```
REACT_APP_ENV = "prod"
```

**.env.staging**

```
REACT_APP_ENV = "staging"
```

**.env.development**

```
REACT_APP_ENV = "development"
```

So that you can create a function in your utils file.

```
export const isProdMode = (): boolean => {
  if (process.env.REACT_APP_ENV === 'prod') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your webpack configuration - simply check if minifying has been enabled for your js code, which would only be the case in production. E.g. I have disabled logging with this simple trick. The element.type.name will be renamed by minifying.

```js
    const MyElement = ({isProduction}) => (<div>Environment: {isProduction?'Production':'Development'}</div>);

    const MyElementEl = React.createElement(MyElement);
    const isProduction = (MyElementEl.type.name !== 'MyElement');

    if(isProduction) //will be true when your js sources are minified 
        console = { ...console, logX: console.log, log: () =>{ } };
        
    ReactDOM.render(<MyElement isProduction={isProduction}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div id="app" />
    </body>
```