# React | change axios baseURL according to the environment variable

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

The problem is that I want to change the baseUrl according to the environment variable.
Currently I have webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js How can I solve this?

Example :

```
dev :
I want to call api url by http://abc:9090

prd :
I want to call api url by http://gef:1234
```

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469836/detecting-production-vs-development-react-at-runtime#35470995