# Angular2 how to set templateUrl base path

Tags: angular

In Angular2, I have something like `templateUrl = 'templates/app.component.html'` during development. But in deployment, i need the url to be something like `templateUrl = '/static/angular_templates/app.component.html'`. It bites to have to change the url at every single place. Is there an easy way to set a base url and do something like

```
templateUrl = BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH+ '/app.component.html'
```

so i only need to update `BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH` when switching from development to production? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TypeScript you can use static variables, like :

```
export class AppTemplateConstants {

    public static get BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH(): string { return 'YOUR_PATH_HERE'; }

}
```

To import this :

```
import { AppTemplateConstants } from '../shared/constants/AppTemplateConstants';
```

To use this :

```
templateUrl: AppTemplateConstants.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH + 'app/path/component.html'
```

Comment: Isn't it rather: `AppTemplateConstants.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH`, @Adrien? :-)

Comment: Hum, you're right ... :) I edited my answer to fix this mistake. Thank's for the notice.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH' of undefined(…)

I tried console.log in the export and I can see the string, but not in the @component

Comment: @AdrienTorris I get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'AppTemplateConstants' of undefined

Comment: This won't work with newer Angular versions. `templateUrl` will be replaced by a require call by angular cli internally. The require argument must be a string literal. Otherwise webpack cannot resolve the dependency. (Yes, the template is in fact a dependency like other imports later)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired effect without changing the `templateUrl` all over your code base by using `UrlResolver`, available since [2.0.0-alpha.36](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-59).

```
import {UrlResolver} from '@angular/compiler';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

let MyApp: any;

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [{provide: UrlResolver, useValue: new UrlResolver("http://localhost/app")}],
  bootstrap: [MyApp]
})
class AppModule {
}

export function main() {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

This will bootstrap your application with a custom instance of `UrlResolver` that has a base url that you specify. You can even have finer control over resolving the paths by extending the UrlResolver class:

```
class MyUrlResolver extends UrlResolver {
  resolve(baseUrl: string, url: string): string {
    // Serve CSS files from a special CDN.
    if (url.substr(-4) === '.css') {
      return super.resolve('http://cdn.myapp.com/css/', url);
    }
    return super.resolve(baseUrl, url);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [{provide: UrlResolver, useClass: MyUrlResolver}],
  bootstrap: [MyApp]
})
...
```

([source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/examples/compiler/ts/url_resolver/url_resolver.ts))

Note: for this to work, you most likely need to use [component-relative paths](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/) by providing `moduleId: module.id,` in your component definition, e.g.:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,  // use component-relative paths
    selector: 'dialogs',
    templateUrl: './dialogs.html',
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I use DependencyInjection to pass around an `EnviromentSettings` object where I store environment variables such as BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH.

Kind of simple and nice mechanism in my opinion.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should define a constant in your build environment, using webpack, for example, you can use the `webpack.DefinePlugin`: [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

you can use one common class/service in which you can store all your global variables and inject that class at the time of bootstrapping by doing so that class is now available to all another classes/components throughout the app and also now you can easily change your variable value by just changing at one place instead of making changes in all components here is example of same -

```
import {Component, Injecable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injecable()
export class GlobalService {
public BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH: string;

    constructor() {
        this.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH = "Your Path Goes Here";
    }
}
```

and just register this service class in bootstrap like this -

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,GlobalService , XYZ...
]);
```

Now this `GlobalService` class is available to all another classes,

also now no need to register this class in the list of providers every time when you use because angular itself initialize this to all components, Now use these global variables/function in any class like this -

```
import {GlobalService} from './GlobalService';
...// stuff here
templateUrl: GlobalService.BASE_TEMPLATE_PATH + 'app/path/component.html'
```