# Setting the base url for an individual package using SystemJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs

I have the following structure to my site

```
ng2
  main.js
  components
    app.component.js
@angular
  platform-browser-dynamic
    platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
```

In my SystemJS config I have the following...

```
var config = {
  map: map,
  baseURL: '/ng2',
  packages: packages
}

System.config(config);
```

This works great except the angular dependencies end up having the url...

> http://localhost:3000/ng2/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

Which of course needs to be

> http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

Is there a way to set this on a particular package?

Answer (score 0):

I am not accepting this because I think there is a better answer but for now I am doing this instead...

[Angular2 how to set templateUrl base path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797977/angular2-how-to-set-templateurl-base-path)

Then I just get rid of the base url and set `System.import('ng2/main')`