# Still getting NODE_ENV console warning from Redux after setting it via webpack

Tags: redux

I'm getting

```
You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use loose-envify (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or DefinePlugin for webpack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031) to ensure you have the correct code for your production build.
```

I tried to fix it by adding following codes to my webpack config. But it didn't work for Redux. However, following codes did fix a similar warning from React.

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }
  }),
  ...
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you find out the answer as I am doing the same thing and getting this error as well.

Comment: @EncorePTL not yet

Answer (score 1):

Got it work after some trial and error

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }
    })
]
```

Then in my package.json I run npm script "build:webpack" which does the following

```
"build:webpack": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"'"
```

Comment: I think command line `--define` is sufficient for both React and Redux