# Why webpack gives an error for about NODE_ENV?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack+react+redux on a web application. And I am using `webpack-dev-server` to launch dev web server. When I access my application on a browser, it gives below error messages on the console:

```
Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. 

You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use loose-envify  to ensure you have the correct code for your production build.
```

Below is my webpack.config.js file. I didn't specify production mode, why webpack gives me such warning message? And how can I get rid of it?

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

const PATHS = {
  react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js'),
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app/index.jsx',
    android: './app/utils/platform_android.js',
    ios: './app/utils/platform_ios.js',
    web: './app/utils/platform_web.js',
    vendor: [
      'axios',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'react-router-redux',
      'redux',
      'redux-thunk',
      'react-alert',
      'sha1',
      'moment',
      'nuka-carousel',
      'react-cookie',
      'material-ui',
      'react-spinkit',
      'react-tap-event-plugin',
      'react-tappable',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  relativeUrls: true,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
      normalize_css: __dirname + '/node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css',
    }
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.js$/,
      //   exclude: /node_modules/,
      //   loader: 'jshint-loader'

      // }
    ],
    loaders: [

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets=es2015',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style!css!less",
      },
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
      {test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"},

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader?presets=es2015']
      },
      {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'svg-sprite',
      include: /public\/icons/
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new NpmInstallPlugin({
      save: true // --save
    }),

    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */["vendor"], /* filename= */"[name].bundle.js", Infinity),
  ],
  devServer: {
    colors: true,
    contentBase: __dirname,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 9093,
    progress: true,
    stats: {
      cached: false
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT1**:

I removed this line:

```
react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js'),
```

Then updated the NODE_ENV to development as below:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development")
      }
    })
```

Then I still got the same warning.

```
warning.js:14You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use loose-envify (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or DefinePlugin for webpack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031) to ensure you have the correct code for your production build.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you get now is because you are letting Webpack minify your build, but you are still setting `NODE_ENV` to `development`.

If you use `UglifyJsPlugin` you should always set `NODE_ENV` to `production`. If you're not building for production, remove `UglifyJsPlugin` to not get any warnings.

Webpack, React and Redux try to give you some best practice hints here. In development mode (`NODE_ENV` not set to `production`), they all give more warnings and have lower performance. When you minify them they assume you're running a production build. For production builds, they really expect `NODE_ENV` to be set correctly.

So in short:

- Production builds: set `NODE_ENV` to `production` and use `UglifyJsPlugin`.
- Dev builds: set `NODE_ENV` to `development` and don't use any minification plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to say it more clear than webpack does...

You are not in a production build mode, but using a minified version of React. Use a non-minified one, so replace

```
react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js'),
```

with

```
react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.js'),
```

or whatever place where you have your react **not minified**.

And this is not an error - it is a warning, so you can still work with this one.

Just another thing by the way: `path.join` adds proper slashes for each operating system. What you do here is

```
path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js')
```

when you should go with

```
path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react', 'dist', 'react.min.js')
```

This is how the `path` should be properly used

Comment: Does that mean I need to define two webpack config files? One for dev mode, one for production mode? And most of these two files are same with just a few lines different, right?

Comment: It seems that I didn't use the react path anywhere in my config file so I removed it. I have edited my post and still got the same error.

Comment: @ZhaoYi well two webpack files is quite a normal practice, however you can use a non minified version and a UglifyJS webpack plugin on top of it which will minify everything including your code. Concerning the second comment: is the error the same? About react???

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing below configuration from webpack.config.js for development build. It seems that this plugin will compress the js code which is not suitable for development mode.

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
  },
  output: {
    comments: false,
  },
})
```