# Minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means slower development build of Redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

So this is the full error: 
**You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux.**

I am using a 3rd party charting library, CanvasJS, which needs access to the global scope. When I import it within any of my modules it seems the actual code breaks when in the browser (probably a `this` problem).

I solved it by using Webpack, and having gulp bundle the bundle.min.js with the minified Charting library.

This works just fine until I try a production build. I think the reference to **CanvasJS** may have gotten mangled in the process.

My Webpack.config file:

```
 var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
 var webpack = require('webpack');
 var path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/main.js",
  resolve: {
   alias: {
    'react': 'react-lite',
    'react-dom': 'react-lite'
   }
  }, 
  module: {
  loaders: [
    {
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     query: {
       presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
       plugins: [ 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
     }
   }
 ]
},
output: {
  path: __dirname + "/public/build/",
  filename: "bundle2.min.js"
},
plugins: debug ? [] : [
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  //  new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
],
};
```

I have tried to mark CanvasJS as External, but this did not work either. How can I get Redux to not "run slow", and have references to global objects?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add:

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  })
```

For your production config

Comment: I am getting this error in ALL environments. I tried what you have Dmitriy to no avail. Curious why this is happening in all my environments.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`webpack -p`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#cli-alternatives). That will enable UglifyJSPlugin as well. The [check](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v4.0.0/src/index.js#L15-L27)'s location for the curious.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "mode" helped to fix the issue like below with webpack 4, either you can use value for mode :development/production for an appropriate configuration file.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
};
```