# Receiving 'you are using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'' error on development builds of react native app

Tags: react-native, redux

According to [currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means slower development build of Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130860/currently-using-minified-code-outside-of-node-env-production-this-means-s), the solution is to update the webpack config, but as far as I know react-native doesn't use webpack.

Is there a way to make react-native use unminified code in development mode? or set NODE_ENV to production when running locally? I'm not sure what the best solution should be.

Comment: did you manage to solve this tzl?