# Page keeps loading when tests run in headless mode using phantomjs

Tags: selenium, automation, phantomjs, nightwatch.js, headless

I am using Nightwatch.js with phantomjs to run tests in headless mode.

There is a loading icon provided before any page loads.

***Issue*:** Whenever I run tests locally using chrome browser, all tests work fine but when I run same tests in headless mode(using safari here,tried with chrome as well: same result), it just fails at the page with the 'loading' icon always as if the page never loaded completely.

My nightwatch.json looks as follows:

```
 {
   "src_folders": [
   "test"
   ],
   "output_folder": "./reports",
   "page_objects_path": "pages",
   "globals_path": "./globals.js",
   "selenium": {
     "start_process": true,
     "server_path": "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/selenium.jar",
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "port": 4444,
     "cli_args": {
       "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/chromedriver",
     }
   },

   "test_settings": {
   "default": {
     "silent": true,
     "test_workers": true,
    "detailed_output": true,
    "launch_url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "screenshots": {
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "./screenshots",
      "on_error": true,
      "on_failure": true
     },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true
    }
  },
    "headlessMacOSSafari": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
         "browserName": "phantomjs",
         "javascriptEnabled": true,
         "acceptSslCerts": true,
         "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.2 Safari/602.3.12",
         "phantomjs.binary.path": "./node_modules/.bin/phantomjs"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I have a globals.js file which includes:

```
 waitForConditionTimeout: 15000
```

which is 15 sec still the tests always fail in headless mode at the same 'loading' icon place but always passes when runs locally.

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: Is there a way to collect output of PhantomJS's [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback? Also - is PhantomJS the latest version?

Comment: @Vaviloff: i am not able to launch application (running against localhost). I get a blank see. phantomjs page.onError gives:
"You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. 
This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. 
You can use loose-envify (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or DefinePlugin for webpack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031) to ensure you have 
the correct code for your production build."