# DefinePlugin usage with multiple identifiers

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage):

> Each key passed into DefinePlugin is an identifier or multiple
>   identifiers joined with `.`.

Could you provide an example of the latter, i.e. "multiple identifiers joined with `.`."?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack - DefinePlugin method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502886/webpack-defineplugin-method)

Comment: @Dom, no it's not a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means like this (from the example on the page) where the key is "process.env"

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
     NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
   }
}
```