# Setting environment variables after webpack build

Tags: heroku, webpack

I'm currently trying to deploy my Webpack 2/React/Redux application on Heroku, and I'm trying to build locally then deploy to Heroku. The problem with this is that the PORT environment variable supplied by Heroku is set post build - so the process.env.PORT value is undefined when I build locally.

I could build on the Heroku server, but it's very slow and has a 60s boot timeout.

I was wondering if there was a way to set environment variables AFTER building?

Answer (score 0):

To build your app on Heroku, it is common to use the `postinstall` script in your package.json (See [official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) for further details). Alternatively, you can add an npm script called `heroku-postbuild`.

<s>In both cases, the `$PORT` environment variable should be set already and you do not have the 60s time out restriction during build.</s>

Just to make sure I understand your question right: to read the environment variables during runtime is not possible after build (afaik), you would have to tell Webpack not to replace the `process.env` variables. But you can set them by a defined value during build time (e. g. configurable via the [DefinePlugin, the EnvironmentPlugin or an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)).

UPDATE:

The`$PORT` environment variable is not set during the `postinstall`/`heroku-postbuild` execution time, therefore it is not recommended to hardly compile it into the code as mentioned before. But still, it is recommended to build your app on Heroku using one of `postinstall`/`heroku-postbuild` scripts.

If you want to run your app locally, you need to set your `$PORT` environment variable on your own, like this:

```
$> PORT=8000 node app.js
```