# Custom global process.env variable with Webpack build

Tags: npm, webpack, process

I have a Vue application that's compiled using Webpack. I'm trying to add a variable into the 'npm run dev' command that I can then use globally throughout the project. Currently, I am running 'npm --brand=foo run dev' and consoling 'process.env.brand' in the build.js file returns 'foo'. Now I need to make this available to the rest of the project. Here is my setup:

WEBPACK.DEV.CONF.JS

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')

module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    })
})
```

DEV.ENV.JS

```
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"'
})
```

File structure is Build/build.js + webpack.dev.conf.js and Config/dev.env.js. I tried to add a 'brand' property like the following, but process.env.brand was undefined in this file.

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  brand: process.env.brand
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *UPDATE by [@Linx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6942889/linx) to pass the argument **dynamically directly from
>   command line***
>
> Run the command and pass in the variable like: `npm --brand=foo run dev`
>   Then, variable is then available in the webpack config file as
>   `process.env.npm_config_brand`.

---

Another option is to setting the variable inside the npm script section:

**package.json**

```
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "SET brand=foo& webpack -p"
},
```

*If you are using linux, maybe you should remove the SET* --> `"dev": "brand=foo& webpack -p"`

**Then run the command like**: `npm run dev`

---

In both cases, to make it available for the rest of the project you can use [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            '__BRAND__': process.env.brand,
        })
    ]
}
```

The variable will be accessible in the rest of the project like: `console.log(__BRAND__);`

Comment: I'm not able to test it now, so if this doesn't work, tomorrow I will update my answer. I hope you find a solution... also check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm unable to set the brand in the scripts as this needs to be dynamic, it needs to be equal to what I pass into the npm run command. I did, however, use your advice about using DefinePlugin to set a new '_BRAND_' item which was successful. I am now able to access it throughout the project.

Comment: Ok, if you can solve the part of pass the argument dynamically, add it to the answer. If not, when I know how to do it, I will update it. Good luck.