# .env shows incorrect values

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

So I have a file named `.env` with the following contents

```
NODE_PATH=./src
NODE_ENV=what
TEST=test
```

And I am calling that in my index.js in my react app.

```
 require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env);
```

...

shows the following output

```
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
```

I thought maybe I declared another .env file somewhere else, but thats not the case. I searched my project for the `PUBLIC_URL` and it's not located anywhere in my project. I don't even know what else to check at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CRA then you'll need to do: `REACT_APP_TEST=test` and reload the dev server to have it show up as expected in your app.

Comment: I didnt see in the documentation that they define the NODE_ENV for you

Answer (score 1):

In react code you have to compile the environment variables in at, well, compile time because at run-time there it is only possible to access a fake `process.env` object. Unless you are using server side rendering.

See also: [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `create-react-app` for bootstrap your project then you have to use environment variables like `REACT_APP_NODE_ENV=development`.

After adding any new environment variable, you have to restart the development server.