# How to pass Laravel env data to Vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I need to pull in my Stripe keys from my Laravel `.env` file and pass it into my Vue component.
I read some similar questions on SO and the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix#environment-variables) that mention doing it by simply adding the `MIX` prefix, and I can call `process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY` anywhere in my JS.

**.env**

```
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

MIX_STRIPE_KEY="${STRIPE_KEY}"
MIX_STRIPE_SECRET="${STRIPE_SECRET}"
```

**In my Vue Component:**

```
<template>
{{ stripe }} // Renders process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY (Not the actual key?)
...code
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            stripe: Stripe('process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY'),
...
```

After I did this I recompiled by `npm run dev, production, watch` tried all of them... Still not getting the Stripe key to show in the `app.js` file.

Speaking of the `app.js` file. I tried adding it in there as well.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
 data:{
        stripeKey: 'process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY',
 },
```

Then tried calling `{{  stripKey }}` in the Vue component, but that didn't render correctly either.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If the component is in blade file, I would try to set the value to a "prop" defined in the element. As follow: <my-element :data="{{ env('MIX_STRIPE_KEY') }}"></my-element>

Comment: The component is in a blade file. Doing as you mentioned, how would you use the data in the Vue file?

Comment: Just above the "data" function, define an array called "props" with the "prop" as needed as follows: props: ['stripe'], then in Blade:  <my-element :stripe="{{ env('MIX_STRIPE_KEY') }}"></my-element>

Comment: @AlexandreBarbosa This solution works great as well and might be best for my specific case at the moment. Appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes. Webpack will interpolate the value for you:

```
<template>
{{ stripe }} // Renders process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY (Not the actual key?)
...code
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            stripe: Stripe(process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY),
...
```

Will compile as:

```
<template>
{{ stripe }} // Renders process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY (Not the actual key?)
...code
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            stripe: Stripe("pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
...
```

Comment: ‍♂️ Oh Jeez, thank you, that worked! If you wouldn't mind me asking one more... How/Where would I use the if else statement to use test keys in dev and production keys in production? Similar to this `if ( process.env.Mix_APP_ENV == 'production' ) {
    use production keys
} else {
     use test keys
}`

Comment: hehe, no worries, happy to help! Webpack will similarly swap out `process.env.NODE_ENV` with `production` when building in production mode. So `Stripe(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.MIX_PROD_KEY : process.env.MIX_DEV_KEY)` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Trying to wrap my head around that. Where would you put that statement and should I add both Dev and Production keys to my .env file since Webpack has to compile for it to work?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Behind the scenes, mix uses the webpack define plugin (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) and filters out everything from `.env` that isn't prefixed with `MIX_`. Where you place that is up to you. There are some good suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack I really like the alias config so you can actually separate those in different files to be included based on `NODE_ENV`

Comment: Thank you for all the help. This is good info. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Note for future readers: do not place your STRIPE_SECRET into Mix as this may make it exposed to the browser and any user that decides to snoop in it.