# React Public URL env variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I am trying to access images in my public folder after build, and so I went ahead and created a PUBLIC_URL. I am however having trouble with the filepath structure as the images don't seem to be located.

My `PUBLIC_URL is: PUBLIC_URL = '/Assets/color/'`

I reference it in my components as such:

```
  img_src = weather_array.includes(data.weather_code.value)
    ? (img_src = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}${data.weather_code.value}_day.svg`)
    : (img_src = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}${data.weather_code.value}.svg`);
```

Here is a picture of the file structure for reference.
[image: file-structure-image]

Answer (score 1):

The `process` variable only works on Node.js. In React, so in the browser, we can't use that variable. However, we can go with using Webpack to access the `process` variable. The `DefinePlugin` helps us to pass the server-side variables into client-side while building.
Please see

- [Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)
- [Using environment variables in React](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, webpack **will replace `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` with a fixed value during build.**
So, it may be that you evaluating it, additionaly, causes problems.

Meaning it should be `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in the code, not `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`.

E.g., with my package.json looking like this (the homepage setting influences PUBLIC_URL)...

```
{
  "name": "meetup-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/uvs",
```

... and this below code in App.js...

```
function App() {
  const basePath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path={basePath} exact element={<AllMeetupsPage />}></Route>
            <Route
              path={basePath + "/new-meetup"}
              element={<NewMeetupsPage />}
            ></Route>
            <Route
              path={basePath + "/favorites"}
              element={<FavoritesMeetupsPage />}
            ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

... the build output will have this content (I re-formatted it):

```
("ul", {
    children: [(0, u.jsx)("li", {
        children: (0, u.jsx)(a.rU, {
            to: s,
            children: "All Meetups"
        })
    }), (0, u.jsx)("li", {
        children: (0, u.jsx)(a.rU, {
            to: "/uvs/new-meetup",
            children: "Add New Meetup"
        })
    }), (0, u.jsx)("li", {
        children: (0, u.jsxs)(a.rU, {
            to: "/uvs/favorites",
            children: ["My Favorites", (0, u.jsx)("span", {className: c, children: e.totalFavorites})]
        })
    })]
})
```

(Sorry if this is utter nonsense, I'm a total newbie, only some 2 weeks into front end development.)