# React - ``npm start`` opens the public folder since when I defined the env.PUBLIC_URL variable

Tags: reactjs

I need to acces static contents (images) so I found the PUBLIC_URL variable is the way it's done in React.
Can the path "/public" be changed to something else?
I ask this because I added the
`PUBLIC_URL=https://yourdomain.whatever/public` and all is fine,
but I noticed that `npm start` open the browser in **http://localhost:8000/public** .
If I remove or comment that `PUBLIC_URL` variable it returns to start from **http://localhost:8000** and images are available statically from /public.

So, why (and how) have I to define the PUBLI_URL variable?
Do I actually need it or it's fine to skip because already there by default?
Why the `npm start` open the **http://localhost:8000/public** url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you require to access `PUBLIC_URL` directly and don't think it is good practice to change it. As you may know, that index.html is single page that react always renders, which is inside the `public` directory. So no surprise that when you compile code, it look for `index.html` in `PUBLIC_URL` and renders it. If you want to access certain asset and want to add its path in `index.html` directly, then you can use `PUBLIC_URL` to define asset path, otherwise to access asset in your react code, you can directly access it by providing path as: /path/to/asset/inside/public. For example, If I have image abc.jpeg inside `img` folder in public, then I can access it directly in my react code as:

```
<img src="/img/abc.jpeg" />
```

Comment: Thanks. your example is clear and works fine.
I'm wondering why the tutorial I followed (and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520904/react-public-url-env-variable) for example) makes use of ``process.env.PUBLIC_URL``.