# Webpack conditionally require file base on environment mode

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have 3 config JavaScript files like `config.local.js`, `config.dev.js`, `config.prod.js`. An example of one of these files.

```
// config.dev.js

function Config(){
    return{
        apiUrl: "https://myapi.dev.com/"
    }
}

module.exports = Config;
```

Now I have an entry file that requires this config file. For instance:

```
// register.js

function Register(){
    const config = require("../config");

    // rest of the code to use that config
}
```

My web pack config looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        register: "./app/src/register.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/app/dist",
    },
};
```

I would like that when I run web pack for production (web pack --mode=production), it would bundle the `config.prod.js` file.

Is this possible?

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page: https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/

```js
require('../config.' + process.env.NODE_ENV)
```