# Weird components nomenclature on React error logs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I hope you guys are doing well

For some reason that I could not identify, the React error logs are not giving proper component naming when logging info on the console when regarding to an error:

[image]

[image]

So it basically does not show the component where the error is ocurring...
Does anyone know how to fix this·?

EDIT: I am also receiving the following error after starting development:

> You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV ===
> 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development
> build of Redux. You can use loose-envify
> (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or
> DefinePlugin for webpack ([Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031))
> to ensure you have the correct code for your production build.

Comment: turn off minification for local dev work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how can I do this? I saw my webpack config and it does not have minify on for development

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it turns out that there wasnt a config foor minfiy but there was an optimization for minimize, and I just turned it off and the issue was gonoe

Answer (score 0):

I had an config for minimize into the optimization config insided my webpack.config.dev
Setting this minimize property to false solved the issue

```
optimization:{
  minimize: false
}
```