# How to set VUE_APP_VARIABLE during CI process Azure DevOps

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops, vuejs2, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I'm using VueJS 2.x

In my code, I want to use an environment variable like this:

```
callApi(process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY)
```

The problem is: I want to set the value of this VUE_APP_API_KEY during the CI process in Azure DevOps but my solution doesn't work.

What I have done:

1. Create a variable name API_KEY in pipeline variables.
2. Try to set the value during this task

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Build application
  inputs:
    script: yarn build
  env:
    VUE_APP_API_KEY: $(API_KEY)
```

Does anyone know what wrong with my solution and how to do it the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building your application using Webpack, you have to *inject* your env vars manually:

[Passing environment-dependent variables in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030031/passing-environment-dependent-variables-in-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your YAML script to set the value of the variable and it could output the value I have set.

```
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Build application
    inputs:
      script: echo $VUE_APP_API_KEY
    env:
      VUE_APP_API_KEY: $(API_KEY)
```

You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information about set variable with command link task.

Comment: yes, I know it but when I try to access it through process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY, it's undefined :(